# Change background colour of parent div on child hover in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, hover

I have three coloured boxes in a `div`, all of different colors, and when i `hover` upon any of these boxes i have to make the `background-color` of the parent `div` appear with the same color as the inner-box which is being hovered upon.

CSS:

```
 .t1_colors {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(111,61,69);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="task1" class="task">
    <h2>Task 1</h2>
    <p>Change the background color, of the div that     contains this task, to the color in each box when the box is hovered over.</p>
    <p>When the mouse stops hovering over the box, change the background color back to white.</p>
    <div id="t1_color_one" class="t1_colors" style="background: goldenrod;"></div>
    <div id="t1_color_two" class="t1_colors" style="background: lightgreen;"></div>
    <div id="t1_color_three" class="t1_colors" style="background: palevioletred;"</div>
</div>
```

Our class is using `addEventListener` if that makes anything any easier. Thanks in advance for any feedback, and will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Look in pure JavaScript:

```
<div>
  <div id="child" onMouseOver="this.parentNode.style.background='red'">Hover Me</div>
</div>
```

With jQuery:

```
 $("#child").hover(function(){
     $(this).parent().css("background","red");
 });
```

UPDATE: not Click, it's Hover. Fixed css property name.

Comment: Syntax and spelling errors - `bakground` should read `background` and needs a closing `"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = document.getElementById("task1");//get parent element

var item1 = document.getElementById("t1_color_one");//get child element

item1.addEventListener("mouseover", func, false);//add event listener for first item on mouseover and call func when someone mouse overs it

function func()
{  
  parent.setAttribute("style", item1.getAttribute("style"));//set the style attribute of the parent to the style attribute of the child
}
```

and then you can do something similar for the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer in pure javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event)
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('t1_colors');
    var count_of_divs = divs.length;

    for(var i = 0; i<count_of_divs; i++)
    {
        divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById('task1').setAttribute('style', e.target.getAttribute('style'));
        }, false);

        divs[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById('task1').removeAttribute('style');
        }, false)
    }
}, false);
```

And you can check it in jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qpuaK/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .t1_colors {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(111,61,69);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="task1" class="task">
            <h2>Task 1</h2>
            <p>Change the background color, of the div that     contains this task, to the color in each box when the box is hovered over.</p>
            <p>When the mouse stops hovering over the box, change the background color back to white.</p>
            <div id="t1_color_one" class="t1_colors" style="background: goldenrod;">ugy</div>
            <div id="t1_color_two" class="t1_colors" style="background: lightgreen;">hjk</div>
            <div id="t1_color_three" class="t1_colors" style="background: palevioletred;">jkk</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        try
        {
            function change_bgcolor(elem)
            {
                elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){elem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=elem.style.backgroundColor}, false);
            }

            function f1()
            {
                div_arr=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                for(x in div_arr)
                {
                    if(div_arr[x].parentNode.tagName=="DIV")
                    {
                        change_bgcolor(div_arr[x]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {alert(e);}
        onload=f1();
    </script>
</html>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fvnf9/2/)** here